# How do I put part of Kafka message in Dead Letter Queue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I hava a Kafka Application, written in Java, with configured DeadLetterPublishingRecorer:

```
@Bean
public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer dltPublisherMyApp() {
    return new DeadLetterEnrichAndPublishRecoverer(getDltTemplate("127.0.0.1:9092"),
            (record, exception) -> new TopicPartition(record.topic() + "Error", record.partition()), objectMapper);
}
```

As you can see, DLT topic name has "Error" postfix.
Listener is quite simple:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{__listener.createMyObjectConsumerProperties.topic.name}",
        groupId = "#{__listener.createMyObjectConsumerProperties.topic.consumerGroupId}",
        containerFactory = CREATE_MY_OBJECT_KAFKA_LISTENER_FACTORY)
public void consumeLead(CreateMyObjectRequest content) {
    injectedService.createObjects(content);
}
```

and finally CreateMyObjectRequest

```
public class CreateMyObjectRequest {

private List<SmallObjects> smallObjectsList;}
```

My requirement is to process a list of objects - SmallObject.
In case of any problems/errors, I must put SmallObject to DLT. Not full  CreateMyObjectRequest.
Please give some ideas about how to configure Java application and put only a portion of input message to DLT. I.e. only some SmallObjects, not complete CreateMyObjectsRequest.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

discussed the issue with PM and decided to send SmallObjects one-by-one to Kafka and receive them one-by-one in Consumer.
In case of any error, they will be sent to LDT automatically.